# How to separate a complex exponential into real and imaginary factors?

Tags: complex-numbers

I've spent an embarrassingly long time on a seemingly simple homework problem and am starting to believe that either the solution is wrong or that I am a lot stupider than I thought.

The problem is to show that the expression

$$e^{-i(k_2-k_1)x}e^{-i(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)t}+e^{i(k_2-k_1)x}e^{i(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)t}$$

contains a term which describes completely the time dependence

$$g(x)\cos((\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)t + \phi)$$

where $g(x)$ is real and $\phi$ does not depend on $x$

It seems to me that generally, the solution relies on the existence of a real function function $g(x)$ and an x-independent $\phi$ such that

$$e^{-if(x)}+e^{if(x)}=g(x)(e^{-i\phi}+e^{i\phi})$$

(Note: $f(x)$ is real)

I cannot think of any $\phi$ satisfying this equation that would be independent of $x$

> Assuming $f(x) = (k_2-k_1)x$, what $g(x)$ and $\phi$ would satisfy the equation 
>   $$e^{-if(x)}+e^{if(x)}=g(x)(e^{-i\phi}+e^{i\phi})$$ and the constraints that $g(x)$ is real and $\phi$ is independent of $x$ and non-zero?

Comment: You're aware that $e^{ix} + e^{-ix} = 2\cos(x)$?

Comment: I am, yes. Its important to the larger problem at hand that the x dependence be factored out in the way described.

Comment: I suppose I'm misreading something then because, by inspection, it looks like $g(x) = \cos(\Delta k\cdot x),\quad \phi = 0$ is a solution

Comment: It is a solution to the question I asked but not to the larger problem. That's my fault, I will update to include more context.

Comment: OK, but for general $f(x)$, is it just that $g(x) = \left(1 - \frac{f^2(x)}{2!} +  \frac{f^4(x)}{4!} - \cdots\right).\,\phi=0$ for real $f(x)$?  Or is it that $f(x)$ is complex valued?

Comment: I've updated the question. Hopefully the context makes it clear why phi cant be zero in this problem. I intended for f(x) in the original question to be real. Thank you for helping me out with this - the homework was turned in yesterday but I wont be able to sleep until i figure this out.

Comment: The problem, as stated, is very much ill-defined (or trivial, depending on how you want to think about it). Consider the simpler problem "prove that the expression $A$ contains a term of the form $B$". The solution is $A=B+(A-B)$, which obviously contains a term of the form $B$, but in an absolutely trivial way. In any case, I voted to migrate this to Math.SE, as this is a pure-math problem, with no physics involved (even if it comes from solving a physics problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Assuming $f(x) = (k_2-k_1)x$, what $g(x)$ and $\phi$ would satisfy the equation 
>   $$e^{-if(x)}+e^{if(x)}=g(x)(e^{-i\phi}+e^{i\phi})$$ and the constraints that $g(x)$ is real and $\phi$ is independent of $x$ and non-zero?**

Any time you see $e^{-if(x)}+e^{if(x)}$, you can replace it with $2\cos\left(f(x)\right)$.  So to answer this question as it stood *before* the unmotivated addition of the "non-zero" condition, you could take $g(x) = \cos\left(f(x)\right)$ and $\phi=0$.  But if you really want it to be nonzero, note that since $e^{-i\phi}+e^{i\phi} = 2\cos\phi$, you can quite generally pick *any* value for $\phi$ as long as $\cos\phi \neq 0$, and then set
\begin{equation}
  g(x) = \frac{\cos\left(f(x)\right)} {\cos\phi}.
\end{equation}
This is why AccidentalFourierTransform is saying that the problem is ill defined: there's no single answer to it.

Now, looking at your original expression, and remembering that $e^A e^B = e^{A+B}$, we have
\begin{align}
  e^{-i(k_2-k_1)x}e^{-i(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)t}
  + e^{i(k_2-k_1)x} e^{i(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)t}
  &=e^{-i(k_2-k_1)x-i(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)t}
  + e^{i(k_2-k_1)x+i(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)t} \\
  &=2\cos \left[(k_2-k_1)x+(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)t\right] \\
  &=2\cos \left[(k_2-k_1)x\right] \cos\left[(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)t\right]
    -2\sin \left[(k_2-k_1)x\right] \sin\left[(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)t\right]
\end{align}
If you're literally asking to show how that expression "contains a term" like $g(x)\cos\left[(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)t + \phi\right]$... well just set $\phi=0$ and $g(x) = 2\cos \left[(k_2-k_1)x\right]$.  (Remember that a "term" is one part of a sum, whereas a "factor" is one part of a product, so you can see that "term" in the result above.)

---

**EDIT**: Given the OP's comments, I think I can rephrase the original question as:

> Find $g(x)$ and $\phi$ such that
>   \begin{equation}
>   g(x) \cos[(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)t + \phi] + h(x)
>   =
>   e^{-i(k_2-k_1)x}e^{-i(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)t}
>   + e^{i(k_2-k_1)x} e^{i(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)t},
> \end{equation}
>   where $h(x)$ is an arbitrary function independent of time.

It's not hard to get around the addition of $h(x)$ by simply differentiating both sides of this equation with respect to time.  Using the result I showed above, this gives us
\begin{equation}
  -g(x) \sin[(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)t + \phi] (\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)
  =
  -2\sin \left[(k_2-k_1)x+(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)t\right](\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1),
\end{equation}
which simplifies to
\begin{equation}
  g(x) \sin[(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)t + \phi]
  =
  2\sin \left[(k_2-k_1)x+(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)t\right].
\end{equation}
Now, this must be true for all values of $t$, so let's just pick two values and see where it leads.  First, take $t=0$ and we get
\begin{equation}
  g(x) \sin[\phi]
  =
  2 \sin \left[(k_2-k_1)x\right].
\end{equation}
Then, take $t = \pi/[2(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)]$ and simplify to find
\begin{equation}
  g(x) \cos[\phi]
  =
  2 \cos \left[(k_2-k_1)x\right].
\end{equation}
We can divide the first of these by the second to eliminate $g(x)$ and solve for $\phi$:
\begin{equation}
  \tan\phi = \tan \left[(k_2-k_1)x\right].
\end{equation}
So, as you can see, $\phi$ cannot be independent of $x$ unless $k_2=k_1$.

Comment: My fault again. All the time dependence needs to be contained in the term in question. I will update the question. Sorry and thank you.

Comment: If this question goes dead I'll accept this as the answer because it technically is an answer to the question as I wrote it

Comment: Maybe I'm bad at writing questions. But this discussion left me convinced that $\phi$ necessarily depends on x for any non-trivial solution. I'll just ask the teacher on monday. Thanks to all involved. I'll work on my question writing skills.

Comment: With your new clarification, I've edited my answer to show that indeed $\phi$ must depend on $x$ unless $k_1 = k_2$.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you.